# How to Implement Custom Calendar in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I need to use custom calendar instead of `SwiftUI` `DatePicker`. For this purpose I added `pod 'KDCalendar', '~> 1.8.9'` in the `Podfile` after that `MyCalendar` structure created as following:

```
import SwiftUI
import KDCalendar

public struct MyCalendar: UIViewRepresentable {

    public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CalendarView {
        return CalendarView()
    }

    public func updateUIView(_ calendar: CalendarView, context: Context) {
        let date: Date = Date()
        calendar.selectDate(date)
    }
}
```

When I'm going to use it in any stack it's shows only the week name and other parts of the calendar omitted from view and following errors occurred:

[image]

```
[Assert] negative or zero item sizes are not supported in the flow layout
```

Your cooperation highly expected to resolve this issue.

Comment: Stack do not work as expected in case of scroll view or table view. As I am seeing, KDCalendar include table view. So you can try to keep calendar view outside the stack view.

Comment: When I added it's to sheet, also same things happened!

Comment: Try https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar

Comment: Customisable  as you want -> https://github.com/yodagamaheshan/DateGrid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try **FSCalendar** too. It's little bit complex where there is lots of options for configurability. Please find the simplest implementation of **FSCalendar** as following:

### Usage

---

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import FSCalendar

MyCalendar().frame(minWidth: 200, minHeight: 320).padding(.leading, 5)
```

#### MyCalendar

---

```
struct MyCalendar: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MyCalendar>) -> MyCalendarController {
        let calendar: MyCalendarController = .init()
        return calendar
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ calendar: MyCalendarController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<MyCalendar>) {
        // MARK: - TODO
    }
}
```

#### MyCalendarController

---

```
class MyCalendarController: UIViewController, FSCalendarDelegateAppearance {
    let secondary: UIColor = .parse(0xE0B355)
    let primary  : UIColor = .parse(0x346C7C)
    let tersiary : UIColor = .parse(0xE7EEEF)
    
    fileprivate let formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    fileprivate weak var calendar: FSCalendar!
    
    override func loadView() {
        let width: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 40
        let frame: CGRect  = .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 300)
        let view:  UIView  = .init(frame: frame)
        self.view = view
        
        let calendar: FSCalendar = .init(frame: frame)
        calendar.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        calendar.dataSource = self
        calendar.delegate = self
        
        view.addSubview(calendar)
        self.calendar = calendar
        
        calendar.calendarHeaderView.backgroundColor = self.primary
        calendar.calendarWeekdayView.backgroundColor = self.primary
        calendar.appearance.headerTitleColor = self.tersiary
        calendar.appearance.weekdayTextColor = self.tersiary
        
        calendar.appearance.eventSelectionColor = self.tersiary
        calendar.appearance.eventDefaultColor = self.primary
        calendar.appearance.eventOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -7)
        
        calendar.appearance.todaySelectionColor = self.primary
        calendar.appearance.selectionColor = self.secondary
        calendar.appearance.todayColor = self.primary
        
        calendar.appearance.titleWeekendColor = self.secondary
        calendar.appearance.titleDefaultColor = self.primary

        calendar.swipeToChooseGesture.isEnabled = true
        let scopeGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: calendar, action: #selector(calendar.handleScopeGesture(_:)));
        scopeGesture.delegate = self
        calendar.addGestureRecognizer(scopeGesture)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.calendar.scope = .month
        self.calendar.select(Date.init())
        self.calendar.accessibilityIdentifier = "calendar"
    }
}
```

#### Extensions

---

```
extension MyCalendarController: FSCalendarDataSource {
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, didSelect date: Date, at monthPosition: FSCalendarMonthPosition) {
        debugPrint("did select date \(self.formatter.string(from: date))")
        let selectedDates = calendar.selectedDates.map({self.formatter.string(from: $0)})
        debugPrint("selected dates is \(selectedDates)")
        if monthPosition == .next || monthPosition == .previous {
            calendar.setCurrentPage(date, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

extension MyCalendarController: FSCalendarDelegate {
    func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, boundingRectWillChange bounds: CGRect, animated: Bool) {
        self.calendar.frame.size.height = bounds.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

extension MyCalendarController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        debugPrint("UIGestureRecognizer")
        return true
    }
}

extension UIColor {
    static func parse(_ hex: UInt32, alpha: Double = 1.0) -> UIColor {
        let red   = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF0000) >> 16)/256.0
        let green = CGFloat((hex & 0xFF00) >> 8)/256.0
        let blue  = CGFloat(hex & 0xFF)/256.0
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }
}
```

Comment: I  appreciate you doing this! All looks good - I have this implementation rendered in my project now and will do some tweaking and try to learn the methods for configuration.. One last question: What is `ThemeSettings.width` in your code? My guess is it is something specific to your project because I found no other references to it in `FSCalendar` or Swift. I have it "working" with a random `Float` I picked out of my head just to make it build. If you could share what that does that would be appreciated as I assume it is doing something more clever with getting the width of the device?

Comment: You have to use `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` instead of `ThemeSettings.width` or any calculated value as your demand.  It's used for initialisation nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

To view **KDCalendar**, simply need to add **dataSource** and **delegate** as below. This will resolve the **KDCalendar** rendering issue.

---

```
import SwiftUI
import KDCalendar

public struct MyCalendar: UIViewRepresentable {
    var date: Date = .init()

    public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> CalendarView {
        let calendar: CalendarView = .init()
        calendar.setDisplayDate(self.date, animated: false)
        calendar.selectDate(self.date)
        calendar.dataSource = self
        calendar.delegate = self
        return calendar;
    }

    public func updateUIView(_ calendar: CalendarView, context: Context) {
        calendar.selectDate(self.date)
    }
}

extension MyCalendar: CalendarViewDataSource {
    public func startDate() -> Date {
        return Date.init()
    }

    public func endDate() -> Date {
        var month:DateComponents = .init()
        month.month = 2
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: month, to: Date.init())!
    }

    public func headerString(_ date: Date) -> String? {
        return nil
    }
}


extension MyCalendar: CalendarViewDelegate {
    public func calendar(_ calendar: CalendarView, didDeselectDate date: Date) {}
    public func calendar(_ calendar: CalendarView, didScrollToMonth date: Date) {}
    public func calendar(_ calendar: CalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, withEvents events: [CalendarEvent]) {}
    public func calendar(_ calendar: CalendarView, didLongPressDate date: Date, withEvents events: [CalendarEvent]?) {}

    public func calendar(_ calendar: CalendarView, canSelectDate date: Date) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this method, did the event manager functions work properly? I have used your method to make CalendarView UIView, UIViewRepresentable. The calendar has rendered properly but the date selector and event manager does not work. Did you come across this?

Comment: Hi, [Gene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8003362). Actually there were some issues to add event `calendar.addEvent(title: String, date: Date)` or `calendar.addEvent(title: String, date: Date, duration: NSInteger) `. Also there was a warning like `[Assert] negative or zero item sizes are not supported in the flow layout`. Why we decided to use **FSCalendar** instead of it. **FSCalendar** little bit complex but lots of feasibility and configurability. `UIViewControllerRepresentable` will help you to implement **FSCalendar**.

Comment: could you share your implementation of FSCalendar in SwiftUI for the community?

Comment: Hi, [Gene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8003362). Please find the second answer, hope it will solve your problem, also help the community.

Comment: This can be customisable as you want -> https://github.com/yodagamaheshan/DateGrid